Как в форму симфони добавить из контроллера параметр и провалидировать?
Есть сущность, в ней есть уникальное поле слаг, в сущности для него я делаю проверку
#[UniqueEntity(
  fields: 'slug',
  message: 'Слаг для этого заголовка уже занят',
)]

Но слаг у меня может быть пустой
if($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if(!trim($domain->getSlug())) {
                $transliterator = \Transliterator::create('Russian-Latin/BGN');

                $domain->setSlug((string) $slugger->slug((string) $transliterator->transliterate($domain->getTitle()))->lower());
            }

            if($form->isValid()) {
                $entityManager->persist($domain);
                $entityManager->flush();

                $this->addFlash('success', 'Домен создан.');

                return $this->redirectToRoute('panel_admin_app_domain');
            }
        }

Пытаюсь сделать так, т.е если слаг пустой в сущности которая передана в форму, то я генерирую слаг, но в этом случае тогда при isValid  не работает проверка UniqueEntity и вместо проверки просто падает ошибка.
Как правильно на стороне контроллера вставить слаг в сущность которая передана в форму

какая ошибка падает непонятно
